# How can I get the autocomplete feature of the command "sudo service squid..."?

Tags: command-line, services, auto-completion, squid

I can't type in my console:

```
$sudo service squi
```

and press TAB and get the remain part of the command completed (*squid3*), neither the *start*, *stop* and *restart* parameters as I'm used to do with others services.

How can I fix that for squid3 package? I just have the problem with squid, with ssh no problem at all. I can execute the command (`sudo service squid3 stop`) without problems, I just can't use the nice autocomplete feature ;)

Comment: post the op of *ls -lht /etc/init.d/squid3*

Comment: That file don't exist there. squid3 package don't have it.